# bsdtar gives (Empty error message) when trying to extract an ISO

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, unix

On High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65), trying to `bsdtar -xf something.iso` fails with:

```
bsdtar: (Empty error message)
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I have plenty of disk space left and know that the ISO indeed works. For example, try [a debian stretch installer ISO](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/9.5.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.5.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso) (that's what I originally tried it on).

According to `bsdtar --help`:

```
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

Currently installing latest libarchive via homebrew to see if this persists.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great solution, but it's possible that the `bsdtar` shipped with High Sierra is buggy (if I get time, I'll bisect the libarchive repo to see where this occurred).

A workaround is to install the latest with homebrew:

```
brew install libarchive
```

This formula is keg only, though so you'll need to add `$(brew --prefix libarchive)/bin` to your `PATH` to be able to invoke with just `bsdtar`.